# How to style a vaadin component using css?

Tags: java, css, vaadin

I get a vaadin project looking like this:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import com.vaadin.annotations.StyleSheet;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.label.LabelState;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Grid;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;


@StyleSheet ("stylesheet.css")

@Theme("mytheme")
public class MyUI extends UI {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
            Label lb = new Label("VAADIN PROJECT");
            lb.setStyleName("mystyle");
            layout.addComponent(lb);
            setContent(layout);
 
       
    }
    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

And a .css file that is situated in the same directory as the main file:

```
.mystyle {
    color: red;
    font-size: 180px;
    pading-left: 30px;
}
```

When i'am trying to run the project,it's print only the text with no more changes. How can i fix it ?
[MY RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE8d1.jpg)

Comment: I would recommend to read Vaadin documentation about themes first https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/themes/themes-creating.html

Comment: When you have read the above, you will notice that @StyleSheet ("stylesheet.css") is not needed. You can add the css rules to VAADIN/themes/mytheme/mytheme.scss file.

Comment: I have the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76211336/css-style-do-not-applied-vaadin

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [basic starter of Vaadin](https://start.vaadin.com/). It imports a CSS file for the overall view and a CSS file for the specific view.

You can see that `HelloWorldView` has the annotation `@CssImport("./styles/views/helloworld/hello-world-view.css")`. This results in importing a CSS file only for this view.

The class `MainView` forms the parent/border for the other views. It also imports a CSS file with specific attributes for the `MainView` with the annotation `@CssImport("./styles/views/main/main-view.css")`.

The respective files can be found in the `frontend` folder of the application.

Comment: This is a good answer for Vaadin Flow (version 14+), but the question is most probably related to v8 (based on the imports of the class).